# issue with public key stripe in Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Hey I did all good what I could can't find any error or a miss displaced the keys has anybody ever had this issue ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgCu5.png)

Comment: Did you cycle the API keys?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you certain you are using the right API key and not a test/sample or otherwise out-of-date one?

Comment: they're not the best ones if that's what u mean ?

Comment: test ones * yes they the registered ones not a test ones

Comment: on the stripe dashboard I can see "API requests
5 successful requests
0 errors
"

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided shows that you passed in a key that starts with `ssk_live`. Stripe secret keys always start with `sk_`, so it looks like you had a copy paste error.

If you remove that first `s` it should work as expected.